# Using an ivar inside a method which is called from a block

Tags: objective-c

I want to use an ivar in a method that is being called from a block. Is it fine to call the ivar directly from it without causing a retain cycle?
I have seen other questions related to calling properties- saying that we 'can' use self. Just wanted to make sure about ivars, can we call ivar directly or do we need to use **self->_myInstanceVariable** explicitly?

```
__weak MyClassName *weakSelf = self;
[MyBlockCreator myBlock:^{ 
   MyClassName *strongSelf = weakSelf;
   [strongSelf doSomething];
}];

- (void) doSomething {
   _myInstanceVariable = someObject

   // is it fine to use the ivar directly above? 
   // or do we want use self explicitly? 
   // like self->_myInstanceVariable
}
```

Comment: There's no difference between `_someInstanceVar` and `self->_someInstanceVar`. They are the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you don't need to make the reference weak/strong at all, the only situation in which you can cause a retain cycle is if `self` references a block and a strong version of `self` is captured within that block. Since `self` doesn't retain the block in question, there would be no retain cycle even using a strong reference.

```
[Foo doWithBlock:^{
    bar.baz = @"Hello World"; // Totally fine without weak/strong since bar doesn't retain the block here.
}];
```

In situations where `self` holds a strong reference to a block and the block refers to `self`, you need to make the reference weak outside the block then make it strong again inside.

```
__weak id weakSelf = self;
[self doWithBlock:^{
    id strongSelf = weakSelf;
    strongSelf.baz = @"Ok";
}];
```